# should.js not causing mocha test to fail

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, should.js

I'm very new to unit tests, mocha, and should.js, and I'm trying to write a test for an asynchronous method that returns a promise. Here is my test code:

```
var should = require("should"),
    tideRetriever = require("../tide-retriever"),
    moment = require("moment"),
    timeFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD-HH:mm:ss",
    from = moment("2013-03-06T00:00:00", timeFormat),
    to = moment("2013-03-12T23:59:00", timeFormat),
    expectedCount = 300;

describe("tide retriever", function() {
    it("should retrieve and parse tide CSV data", function() {
        tideRetriever.get(from, to).then(
            function(entries) { // resolve
                entries.should.be.instanceof(Array).and.have.lengthOf(expectedCount);
            },
            function(err) { // reject
                should.fail("Promise rejected", err);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

When I manually test the `tideRetriever.get` method, it consistently resolves an array of 27 elements (as expected), but the test will not fail regardless of the value of `expectedCount`. Here is my simple manual test:

```
tideRetriever.get(from, to).then(
    function(entries) {
        console.log(entries, entries.length);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log("Promise rejected", err);
    }
);
```

I can also post the source for the module being tested if it's necessary.

Am I misunderstanding something about Mocha or should.js? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

At some point Mocha started to support returning `Promise` from test instead of adding `done()` callbacks. Original answer still works, but test looks much cleaner with this approach:

```
it("should retrieve and parse tide CSV data", function() {
    return tideRetriever.get(from, to).then(
        function(entries) {
            entries.should.be.instanceof(Array).and.have.lengthOf(expectedCount);
        }
    );
});
```

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/devoto13/fdb04e9df80e057d44357c8123f85b06) for complete example.

**ORIGINAL**

**CAUTION**. Accepted answer works only with normal asynchronous code, not with Promises (which author uses).

Difference is that exceptions thrown from Promise callbacks can't be caught by application (in our case Mocha) and therefore test will fail by timeout and not by an actual assertion. The assertion can be logged or not depending on Promise implementation. See more information about this at [when documentation](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#debugging-promises).

To properly handle this with Promises you should pass `err` object to the `done()` callback instead of throwing it. You can do it by using `Promise.catch()` method (not in `onRejection()` callback of `Promise.then()`, because it doesn't catch exceptions from `onFulfilment()` callback of the same method). See example below:

```
describe("tide retriever", function() {
    it("should retrieve and parse tide CSV data", function(done) {
        tideRetriever.get(from, to).then(
            function(entries) { // resolve
                entries.should.be.instanceof(Array).and.have.lengthOf(expectedCount);
                done(); // test passes
            },
            function(err) { // reject
                done(err); // Promise rejected
            }
        ).catch(function (err) {
            done(err); // should throwed assertion
        });
    });
});
```

**PS** `done()` callback is used in three places to cover all possible cases. However `onRejection()` callback can be completely removed if you don't need any special logic inside it. `Promise.catch()` will handle rejections also in this case.

Comment: You forgot to add "done" as a parameter of the function

Answer (score 4):

When testing asynchronous code, you need to tell Mocha when the test is complete (regardless of whether it passed or failed). This is done by specifying an argument to the test function, which Mocha populates with a `done` function. So your code might look like this:

```
describe("tide retriever", function() {
    it("should retrieve and parse tide CSV data", function(done) {
        tideRetriever.get(from, to).then(
            function(entries) { // resolve
                entries.should.be.instanceof(Array).and.have.lengthOf(expectedCount);
                done();
            },
            function(err) { // reject
                should.fail("Promise rejected", err);
                done();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Note that the way Mocha knows this is an async test and it needs to wait until `done()` is called is just by specifying that argument.

Also, if your promise has a "completed" handler, which fires both on success and failure, you can alternatively call `done()` in that, thus saving a call.

More info at:
http://mochajs.github.io/mocha/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Thank you. I thought the `done` function was only for specifying whether or not the test should be run synchronously with other tests.

Comment: I would double upvote this if I could. The importance of passing the `done` arg to the test (`it`'s callback function) is easy to miss, but the source of a lot of confusion!